# Display NSString using six digits

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, string-formatting

I need to format a string to display with six digits. For example,

```
NSString * firstNumber = @"1";
```

I would like it to be displayed as follows:

```
000001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
firstNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%06d",1];
```

Comment: hank you for your tip Saphrosit was exactly what I was needing